# Manifest file not regarded/working

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar, manifest

This has been driving me nuts, and I have little to no experience with all this maven fluff. I already had it working at first, using my current manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: /Users/avalin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4jnop/1.7.25/slf4j-nop-1.7.25.jar 
        /Users/avalin/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-compiler/7.3.0.Final/drools-compiler-7.3.0.Final.jar 
        /Users/avalin/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-core/7.3.0.Final/drools-core-7.3.0.Final.jar 
        /Users/avalin/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.3.0.Final/kie-api-7.3.0.Final.jar 
        /Users/avalin/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-internal/7.3.0.Final/kie-internal-7.3.0.Final.jar
Main-Class: org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster
```

The manifest should be placed correctly in my resources/META-INF folder,
although IntelliJ is "cleverly" enough attempting to put it into the java-folder instead

But now I suddenly get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(ResourceFactory.java:66)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.getResource(AbstractKieModule.java:299)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:264)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.addResourceToCompiler(AbstractKieModule.java:259)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:228)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:74)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:251)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:219)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:177)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:503)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:331)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
    at org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster.main(EmployeeRoster.java:31)
Avalins-MacBook-Pro:~ avalin$
```

I have this in my pom:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But it seems to have zero effect on absolutely anything...
I need to have my manifest file changes so the "users/avalin" isn't there, but it's generated differently on another computer, as they obviously won't have the same path... Just getting it to work in the first place would probably be a great start

Comment: The mainClass must look like this: `org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster` ...

Comment: Oh yeah woops - Noted and fixed! Didn't do much as far as the problem goes, it seems the manifest is created when intellij creates the jar, and not from maven anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up "fixing" it, and by fixing it, I mean making a workaround.
First of all, intelliJ's "funky" way of building jars, had to be done, not from the build artifact which could seem logical, no, but from the bottom right having "Maven Projects" tab open

After that, everything in the pom started taking effect, and I could make a
separate folder (libs) with all the dependencies using the pom, and have the maven-jar-plugin grab these dependencies from this folder (libs) using libs

Here's what I added:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/libs
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>
                            org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now my project can also be used from different computers, because of the libs-folder. The .jar file ends up in a "target" folder inside the project

Hope this helps someone out there, because finding well-documented material on this subject seems hardly possible, or I might suck at googling. Either way.

Comment: Beter solution for such things is the maven-assembly-plugin or the maven-shade-plugin...

Comment: I already tried with both, they both seemed to disregard my dependencies completely. The "jar-with-dependencies" from the maven-assembly-plugin gave me an error that looked like it had trouble gathering dependencies, that was inside the other dependencies...